# yii2 refresh modal after submit form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, yii2, bootstrap-modal

I want to ask how to refresh the modal after I submit the form in another action? I use yii2.

Here is my code :

**index.php:**

```html
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\grid\GridView;
use yii\bootstrap\Modal;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $searchModel backend\models\KategoriSearch */
/* @var $dataProvider yii\data\ActiveDataProvider */

$this->title = 'Kategoris';
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;

$this->registerJs("
    $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
        var button = $(event.relatedTarget)
        var modal = $(this)
        var title = button.data('title')
        var href = button.attr('href')
        modal.find('.modal-title').html(title)
        modal.find('.modal-body').html('<i class=\"fa fa-spinner fa-spin\"></i>')
        $.post(href).done(function( data ) {
                modal.find('.modal-body').html(data)
        });
    })
");
?>

<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

        'kateg_id',
        'kateg_nama',

        [
          'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
          'template' => '{size} {view} {update} {delete}',
          'buttons' => [
            'size' => function($url, $model, $key) {
                return  Html::a(Html::tag('i','',
                [
                  'class'=>'fa fa-th-list',
                  'title'=>'Size'
                ]),
                [
                  'size',
                  'id'=>$model->kateg_id,
                ],
                [
                  'data-toggle'=>'modal',
                  'data-target'=>'#myModal',
                  'data-title'=>'Size',
                ]);
            }
        ]
      ],
    ],
]); ?>

<?php
  Modal::begin([
    'id' =>'myModal',
    'header' => '<h4 class="modal-title">...</h4>',
    'footer' => Html::button('Close', ['class' => 'btn btn-default','data-dismiss'=>'modal']),
  ]);
  Modal::end();
?>
```

The size button on my grid view will show the modal that returns the render ajax from action size in my controller.

After that here is my size view:

```html
$form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

  <?= $form->field($model, 'ukuran')->textInput(['id'=>'ukuran']) ?>

  <?= $form->field($model, 'kateg_id')->textInput(['id'=>'kategori','type'=>'hidden','value'=>$id]) ?>

  <div class="form-group">
      <?= Html::button('Tambah', [
        'class' => 'btn btn-primary',
        'onclick' =>'
          $.post({
            url: "' . Url::to(['kategori/size']) . '?id="+$("#kategori").val(),
            data:  {ukuran: $("#ukuran").val()},
            success: function(res){
              alert("PROCESS_SUCCES");
            }
          });
        ',
        ]) ?>
  </div>
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
<?php Pjax::begin(['id' => 'pjax-grid-view']); ?>
<div id="grid">

<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    // 'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

        'ukuran_id',
        'ukuran',

        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ],
]); ?>
</div>
<?php Pjax::end(); ?>
```

I'm trying to add refresh after alert but it does not work. It will close the modal and back to index again.

So I'm confused what it should be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.post({
    url: "' . Url::to(['kategori/size']) . '?id="+$("#kategori").val(),
    data:  {ukuran: $("#ukuran").val()},
    success: function(res){
        alert("PROCESS_SUCCES");
    }
});
```

I noticed in your .post call, you don't do anything with the `res` that's passed as the parameter of the success function. You just alert "PROCESS_SUCCES" (is this a macro for something?), and it stops. To modify elements on your page, you would want to select one and use the [`.html()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/html#val) or `.val()` functions to change it. Something like this:

```
$.post({
    url: "' . Url::to(['kategori/size']) . '?id="+$("#kategori").val(),
    data:  {ukuran: $("#ukuran").val()},
    success: function (res) {
        alert("PROCESS_SUCCES");
        $("#my_output_area").html(res);
    }
});
```

Alternatively, you can use [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) instead of `$.post()`.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "' . Url::to(['kategori/size']) . '?id="+$("#kategori").val(),
    data:  {ukuran: $("#ukuran").val()},
    success: function (res) {
        alert("PROCESS_SUCCES");
        $("#my_output_area").html(res);
    }
});
```

Comment: thank you i edit my code use $("#myModal").find(".modal-body").html(res);
and it's work :3